# A curious thought from my math textbook on limits

Tags: limits, complex-numbers, infinity

While solving a limits question from my textbook i came across this statement at the end.Why does this constant ” b” have to be real(why not complex) and how will it affect the limit if it was to be complex.[image]

Comment: Well, for one thing, complex numbers cannot be compared, so a comparison like $1-a>0$ wouldn't be possible. That's why real numbers is a good choice here.

Comment: I l think the book concerns only real numbers and wants to give emphasis that is true for every such number.

Comment: For non-real complex $b$, each $\infty$ in the problem would [mean something different from the extended real $+\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity).

Comment: Building on @J.G. 's observation, the sintactically identical equation $\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{z^2+1}{z+1}-az-b=\infty$ with complex variable and parameters is satisfied if and only if $a\ne 1$. And its "cousin" equation $\lim_{z\to -\infty}\frac{z^2+1}{z+1}-az-b=\infty$ runs into a semantical flaw, if not in the conceptual error of assuming a sign to the point at infinity.

Comment: @Gae.S. [Then there's this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_infinity).